# Font in Navigation too big in IE8 (XP Mode). Rest of the page is ok. Only in navigation

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

---

### edit

This question is solved!

---

Having something weird.

I'm using `html { font-size: 100% }` and `body {font-size: 62.5%}` so I have `1em == 10px` in CSS. I've done this several times before.

Now on my page everything works fine with the font-size, except for the font in the navigation in IE8 and IE7 (XP Mode)

I've fiddled relevant the HTML/CSS code here http://jsfiddle.net/gk4j9/3/

Using modernizr for browser ability switch for the gradients and shadows

Zoom is 100%
Text zoom is medium

[image: Screenshots of IE7, IE8, IE9]

---

edit
For testing go here
http://netrenderer.com/index.php
and test this address
http://fiddle.jshell.net/gk4j9/3/show/light/

---

edit
The font-size is 2em, so should be 20px.
If I change to 1.8em in IE8 wih Developer Tools (18px) it looks quite the same as 2em in IE9 and other browsers

---

### HTML

```html
<div class="l-fullwrap clearfix">
    <header class="page-header">
        <div class="l-header-nav-primary">
            <nav class="primary">
                <ul>
                    <li class="first has-children">
                        <a href="javascript:;">
                            <span>Item 1</span>
                        </a>
                    </li><li class="has-children">
                        <a href="javascript:;">
                            <span>Item 2</span>
                        </a>
                    </li><li class="has-children">
                        <a href="javascript:;">
                            <span>Item 3</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>
```

---

### CSS

```css
html {
  font-size: 100%;
}

html, button, input, select, textarea {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #222;
}

body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


nav ul, nav ol {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
}


a, a:link, a:visited {
  color: #EFAA03;
}
a, a:link, a:visited {
  color: #EFAA03;
}
a:visited {
  color: #551A8B;
}
a, a:link, a:visited {
  color: #EFAA03;
}
a {
  color: #00E;
}








/* Primary Nav */
.l-header-nav-primary {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 45px;
}
nav.primary {
  border-top: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
}
nav.primary,
nav.primary li{
  display: inline-block;
  *zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
.no-cssgradients nav.primary li,
nav.primary li{
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d2d2d2', endColorstr='#979696',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.cssgradients nav.primary li,
nav.primary li{
  line-height: 3.2em;
  padding-right: 1px;
  background: #979696; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d2d2d2 0%, #979696 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#d2d2d2), color-stop(100%,#979696)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d2d2d2 0%,#979696 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d2d2d2 0%,#979696 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d2d2d2 0%,#979696 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top, #d2d2d2 0%,#979696 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: none;
}
nav.primary li.last{
  padding-right: 0;
}
.no-cssgradients nav.primary a,
nav.primary a {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#b6b6b6',GradientType='0' ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.cssgradients nav.primary a,
nav.primary a{
  display: block;
  background: #b6b6b6; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #b6b6b6 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#b6b6b6)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#b6b6b6 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#b6b6b6 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#b6b6b6 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#b6b6b6 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: none;
}
nav.primary a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, 0.65);
  height: 100%;
}
.no-textshadow nav.primary a span{
    display: inline-block;
    *zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    -ms-filter: "Chroma(Color=#E0E0E0) DropShadow(OffX=1, OffY=1, Color=#FFFFFF)";
    filter: Chroma(Color=#E0E0E0) DropShadow(OffX=1, OffY=1, Color=#FFFFFF);
}
.no-textshadow nav.primary li.active a span,
.no-textshadow nav.primary a:focus span,
.no-textshadow nav.primary a:hover span,
.no-textshadow nav.primary a:active span {
    display: inline-block;
    *zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    background-color: transparent;
    -ms-filter: "none";
    filter: none;
}

nav.primary li.active a,
nav.primary a:focus,
nav.primary a:hover,
nav.primary a:active,
.no-cssgradients nav.primary li.active a,
.no-cssgradients nav.primary a:focus,
.no-cssgradients nav.primary a:hover,
.no-cssgradients nav.primary a:active {
  filter: none;
}
.cssgradients nav.primary li.active a,
.cssgradients nav.primary a:focus,
.cssgradients nav.primary a:hover,
.cssgradients nav.primary a:active,
nav.primary li.active a,
nav.primary a:focus,
nav.primary a:hover,
nav.primary a:active {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background:#231F20;
  text-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

​

Comment: I tested it on IE 8 in WinXP, both in normal and compatibility mode and it looks fine

Comment: I tested it here http://netrenderer.com/index.php giving me both the wrong result for IE8 and IE7. IE9 works fine.

Comment: It's working fine. But do you have different text sizes in IE8 and IE7 than you have in IE9????

Comment: 1em equals 100%, which is a relative value. This is not the same as 10 pixels!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

In my XP Mode I do not have the Calibri font installed. So it uses a different font.

Bloody me!